# how to create a xsd schema for this xml?

Tags: xml, ssis, xsd

how can i create a xsd schema for this xml file? 
Trying to create a ssis package to import multiple xml and i don't know to create the xsd schema.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<recordedData>
    <machine>ZSK40-2</machine>
    <date>2013/09/21</date>
    <hour>05:32</hour>-<CollectedData>-<variable>
            <Name>PRODUCT</Name>
            <Value>FILLER 580</Value>
        </variable>-<variable>
            <Name>LOT_NUMBER</Name>
            <Value>CG 00063 0</Value>
        </variable>-<variable>
            <Name>SHIFT_SUPERVISOR</Name>
            <Value>  covaliu l</Value>
        </variable>-<variable>
            <Name>KGH_ALL_SET</Name>
            <Value>0</Value>
        </variable>-<variable>
            <Name>KGH_ALL_REAL</Name>
            <Value>0</Value>
        </variable>-<variable>
            <Name>KGH_F1_SET</Name>
            <Value>0</Value>
        </variable>-<variable>
            <Name>KGH_F1_REAL</Name>
            <Value>0</Value>
        </variable>-<variable>
            <Name>K_F1</Name>
            <Value>43</Value>
        </variable>-<variable>
            <Name>SCREW_RPM_SET</Name>
            <Value>550</Value>
        </variable>-<variable>
            <Name>SCREW_RPM_REAL</Name>
            <Value>550.085388183594</Value>
        </variable>-<variable>
            <Name>TORQUE</Name>
            <Value>1.21340000629425</Value>
        </variable>-<variable>
            <Name>CURRENT</Name>
            <Value>60.1959991455078</Value>
        </variable>-<variable>
            <Name>KW_KG</Name>
            <Value>0</Value>
        </variable>-<variable>
            <Name>KW</Name>
            <Value>-0.990000009536743</Value>
        </variable>-<variable>
            <Name>MELT_PRESSURE</Name>
            <Value>0</Value>
        </variable>-<variable>
            <Name>MELT_TEMPERATURE</Name>
            <Value>214</Value>
        </variable>-<variable>
            <Name>PV1</Name>
            <Value>216</Value>
        </variable>-<variable>
            <Name>SP1</Name>
            <Value>210</Value>
        </variable>-<variable>
            <Name>PV2</Name>
            <Value>239</Value>
        </variable>-<variable>
            <Name>SP2</Name>
            <Value>220</Value>
        </variable>-<variable>
            <Name>PV3</Name>
            <Value>220</Value>
        </variable>-<variable>
            <Name>SP3</Name>
            <Value>220</Value>
        </variable>-<variable>
            <Name>PV4</Name>
            <Value>220</Value>
        </variable>-<variable>
            <Name>SP4</Name>
            <Value>220</Value>
        </variable>-<variable>
            <Name>PV5</Name>
            <Value>209</Value>
        </variable>-<variable>
            <Name>SP5</Name>
            <Value>210</Value>
        </variable>-<variable>
            <Name>PV6</Name>
            <Value>210</Value>
        </variable>-<variable>
            <Name>SP6</Name>
            <Value>210</Value>
        </variable>-<variable>
            <Name>PV7</Name>
            <Value>210</Value>
        </variable>-<variable>
            <Name>SP7</Name>
            <Value>210</Value>
        </variable>-<variable>
            <Name>PV8</Name>
            <Value>210</Value>
        </variable>-<variable>
            <Name>SP8</Name>
            <Value>210</Value>
        </variable>-<variable>
            <Name>PV9</Name>
            <Value>210</Value>
        </variable>-<variable>
            <Name>SP9</Name>
            <Value>210</Value>
        </variable>-<variable>
            <Name>PV10</Name>
            <Value>210</Value>
        </variable>-<variable>
            <Name>SP10</Name>
            <Value>210</Value>
        </variable>-<variable>
            <Name>PV11</Name>
            <Value>220</Value>
        </variable>-<variable>
            <Name>SP11</Name>
            <Value>220</Value>
        </variable>
    </CollectedData>
</recordedData>
```

At least something to get me started with, as i am in a situation where the time presses me.

Comment: Did you try Google? First hit: http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html - an online generator which creates a nice XSD in a matter of seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft XSD Inference tool.
Check that: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28VS.80%29.aspx

Download the tool, put the sample XML in a file, and then run the tool from the command line passing the complete path of your XML file.

Like `>>xsd c:\test.xml`

You will notice that a file named test.xsd is created on the C drive.

Note: don't forget to remove the "-" character from your input xml file

Comment: i did but i get this: Unable to parse any XML input. error: Content is not allowed in prolog. exactly the same  link you shared.

Comment: the xsd schema i receive it's with string data types. i created the database columns as nvarchar. and in ssis i get the error "Error on SSIS, Source destination: cannot convert between unicode &amp; non-unicode string data type" . what i am doing wrong?

Comment: how do i reply with an image please?

Comment: I guess that's something related to the SSIS. Your problem with the XSD generation is now solved. You can post another question and insert the image that you want. You can't post an image in the comment.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it online easily : [Convert XML to XSD online](http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html)

Here is the XSD for the XML that you have mentioned :

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xs:element name="recordedData">
 <xs:complexType mixed="true">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="machine"/>
    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="date"/>
    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="hour"/>
    <xs:element name="CollectedData">
      <xs:complexType mixed="true">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="variable" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Name"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Value"/>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a build in generator in the XML source editor. It doesnt work all the time, but you should give it a try.

[image]

Comment: Made it with xsd.exe from sdk tools. I had some errors but it finaly worked.

Comment: It hasn't worked for me all the time. Let me know how it goes

Comment: will come back with an answer

Comment: You need to use a *data conversion* transform to normalize your string encoding. That should take care of your unicode error